How can I handle file uploads in a React frontend with an Express.js backend and store the files in MongoDB?
I'm working on a full-stack web application using React for the frontend and Express.js for the backend. I need to implement a feature where users can upload files through a form in React, and these files should be handled by the Express.js backend and stored in MongoDB.
Here are the steps I am trying to achieve:
User selects a file in the React frontend.
The file is sent to the Express.js backend via a POST request.
The backend processes the file and stores it in MongoDB.
This is the frontend:
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
  );

And this is the backend code:
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/fileuploads';

// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return {
      filename: file.originalname,
      bucketName: 'uploads',
    };
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ file: req.file });
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));


I am encountering a couple of issues:
When I try to upload a file, sometimes it does not get stored in MongoDB, and I receive a generic error message.
I'm not sure if I'm correctly handling the file upload in the React frontend.
How can I retrieve and display the uploaded files in the frontend?
How can I ensure that files are correctly uploaded from the React frontend to the Express.js backend?
What is the best way to handle errors during the file upload process?
How can I retrieve and display the uploaded files in the React frontend once they are stored in MongoDB?

What's the error you are receiving? I took a fast look at the frontend code and it seems ok.
